# Firebase nested indexing rules

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pyrebase

I want to orderby shopId but it returns:

> "error" : "Index not defined, add ".indexOn": "shopId", for path "/Products", to the rules".

Would appreciate any help thanks!

[image: data]

Rules :

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "now < 1609966800000",  // 2021-1-7
    ".write": "now < 1609966800000",  // 2021-1-7
      "Products":{
        "Records":{
          ".indexOn":["shopId"]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Pyrebase code:

```
result = db.child("Products").order_by_child("shopId").equal_to(shopId).get()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database can only filter the **direct** child nodes on which you run the query. The value which you order/filter on must be at a fixed path under each **direct** child node.

In your data structure you seem to have two unknown keys: `UID` and `unique_recordid`. This means you cannot query for `shopId` from `Products`.

You **can** query the records for a single user:

```
db.child("Products").child("UID of a specific").child("Records")
  .orderByChild("shopId").equalTo("value of shopId")
```

But you can't do the same query on all of `Products` as the path of the `shopId` property is not the same for all child nodes of `Products`.

Also see [Firebase Query Double Nested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27207059/firebase-query-double-nested)

---

If you want to query for records with a specific `shopId`, you'll need in your database a *flat* list of exactly those nodes.

```
Records: {
  "recordid1" : {
    uid: "...",
    productId: "...".
    ...
  },
  "recordid1" : {
    uid: "...",
    productId: "...".
    ...
  }
}
```

On this data you can then query for `productId` and look up the other data, including the UID that is now duplicated for each record.